# Bash: join pipes without deadlock

Tags: bash, pipe, fifo, deadlock

I want to list a bunch of filenames via `find`, pipe them through a utility (let's call this `util`) which outputs a new name for each input name, and then rename each file from the old name to the new.

The most basic solution would be this:

```
find . -print0 | while IFS= read -d '' -r old_name; do
    new_name="$(echo "$file" | util)"
    mv "$old_name" "$new_name"
done
```

The problem with this approach is that `util` is too slow to fire up for each filename separately. So the solution is to launch `util` only once and pipe all the filenames through this single process:

```
find . -print0 >old_names
util <old_names >new_names

exec {old_fd}<old_names
exec {new_fd}<new_names

while IFS= read -d '' -r old_name <&$old_fd &&
      IFS= read -d '' -r new_name <&$new_fd; do
    mv "$old_name" "$new_name"
done
```

This will launch `util` only once, on the other hand it's no longer a pipeline: we have to list all the files into a tmp file, run `util` on this tmp file to get another tmp file, and only then do we actually start the renaming...

I've tried the following to do it in a pipelined way:

```
mkfifo old_names new_names
find . -print0 | tee old_names | util >new_names &

exec {old_fd}<old_names
exec {new_fd}<new_names

while IFS= read -d '' -r old_name <&$old_fd &&
      IFS= read -d '' -r new_name <&$new_fd; do
    mv "$old_name" "$new_name"
done
```

Unfortunately this can deadlock depending on how `util` does input/output buffering...

So my question is: what's the proper way of doing this in bash?

Comment: Depending on the complexity of the transform (`util`), you may be able to use `rename` (the one by Larry Wall).

Comment: To avoid deadlock, don't over complicate it.

Answer (score 1):

A solution without joining pipes:

```
find . -print > infiles
cat infiles | util > outfiles
parallel mv ::::+ infiles outfiles
```

Pro: Extremely simple.
Con: renaming only starts after `util` is done. 2 tempfiles.

```
find . -print > infiles
cat infiles | util | parallel -j1 mv ::::+ infiles -
```

Pro: Renaming will start when `util` starts giving names.
Con: 1 tempfile.

```
find . -print | util | parallel -j1 mv ::::+ <(find . -print) -
```

Pro: Renaming will start when `util` starts giving names.
Con: requires no change to the current directory (otherwise the two `find`s may not give the same.)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the complexity of the transform (util), you may be able to use rename (the one by Larry Wall).

Alternatively

Arrange `util` to output name pairs: `old-name` `new-name`, then

```
find . -print0 | util | xargs -n2 mv -T
```

Alternatively

Try something like this.

```
function a() { 
    echo -n "$1 "
    echo "$1" | sed -e s/a/b/g
}

… | while read arg; do
a "$arg"
done
```

Comment: 1. Thanks, but unfortunately in the real script it's not that simple as simply `mv`-ing the file to its new location, so `rename` wouldn't cut it.

2. I have unfortunately no control over the output format of `util`.